# what is the requirments to run my own web server?

Tags: hosting, webserver

what is the requirments to run my own web server, if i bought for instance Dell PowerEdge T110 II compact tower server, what is the requirments and what do i need to host my own web application on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something your planning to use for your own web app? If so I would definitely recommend not going this route and instead using a service like RackSpace or GoDaddy. Especially if you're doing this out of your home as you probably would be paying a small fortune in extra bandwidth usage.

Also, what are you developing the web app in? If PHP then you'll need a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) server. If you're doing a .net application using Microsoft's Visual Web Developer then you would need a Windows Server.

I hope this helps you.